# What can I do to fix this do-while?

Tags: c, clion

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    float n1, n2, n3, m;
    int op;
    do{
    printf("Digite a primeira nota: ");
    scanf("%f", &n1);
    printf("Digite a segunda nota: ");
    scanf("%f", &n2);
    m = ((n1 + n2) / 2);
    printf("%.2f", m);
    printf("\nDeseja calcular novamente?\n 1 - SIM\n 2 - NAO\n"); scanf("%d", op);
    } while (op == 1);
}
```

This is my code and I expected it to rerun when the user inputs "1" in the last scanf
What did I do wrong?

Comment: do you compile this as c or as c++?

Comment: Please use `-Wall` and `-Werror` compiler options to catch this kind of simple mistakes. [See this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vNm00dSibeZcuGQy).

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
scanf("%d", op);
```

is instant undefined behavior; you need to pass the address like with the other calls (i.e. `&op`). You need to look for compiler warnings, they usually spot these things even though it's not possible from the pure prototype of `scanf()` but takes heuristics.

That said, this kind of field-at-a-time input using `scanf()` on `stdio` is brittle; it's better to read full lines using `fgets()` and then parse the strings. Please note that `scanf()` can *fail*, and you don't check for that. If someone enters `duck` for the final prompt, `op` will never be assigned a value and reading it in the `do{}while` is also undefined behavior.

Comment: Instant at a quantum level? ;-)

Comment: I spent an hour in this code and didn't notice it, thanks!

Comment: Note: They should also check the return value from `scanf` instead of assuming it succeeded, unless they really like infinite loops when `stdin` is closed on them or non-numeric input is provided.

Comment: There is also the matter of main with no return type. Not so serious, but still...